# error: 'link' does not name a type

Tags: android, linux, build

I'm trying to build openssl under android by using android_ndk
The build environment is a linux-ubuntu.

I get the following error:
/openssl-0.9.8k/include/openssl/evp.h:1:1: error: 'link' does not name a type

Do you know what can be wrong?

This is the content of evp.h:

```
link ../../crypto/evp/evp.h
```

what does that link mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever mechanism was used to extract the openssl source code did not understand the unix/linux link mechanism, causing it to erroneously extract symbolic links as files containing the text `link <target of link>`

a tar -tvf of the openssl source shows that the file in question is:

```
lrwxrwxrwx  0 openssl openssl      0 25 Mar  2009 openssl-0.9.8k/include/openssl/evp.h -> ../../crypto/evp/evp.h
```

i.e. the target of the link is what ended up being the content.

You should probably re-extract the source code and try again.